# Visualforce: Link to open a Activity task in Salesforce 1

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, urlhacking

I have worked on displaying a google map which displays all contacts related to a campaign on the campaign detail page.

On every marker, I have added a button which when clicked opens the "Log a call" activity. I needed some fields to be pre-populated so I built my URL like this.

```
<a href="/00T/e?title=Call&what_id=' + locations[i].campaignId + '&followup=1&tsk5=Call&who_id=' + locations[i].recordId + '&retURL=' + locations[i].campaignId + '" target="_blank">' + 'Log a Call</a>
```

This works fine in Salesforce. Now this also needs to work on Salesforce 1. 
The map renders fine and we are able to click the button. But now we are taking to browser for the "Log a Call" activity instead of opening that task in the app itself.

How should the URL be constructed so that it opens in Salesforce 1 and in the browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe its possible to prefill fields in that way on Salesforce1 by default, as if you want to stay inside the SF1 UI (and not open regular pages) you'll need to navigate via JavaScript which doesn't provide the ability to pass extra parameters. In this case you can only navigate to a page to create a record of a particular type through the sforce.one.createRecord() method.

The best you'll be able to do is open a Visualforce page, which can pull parameters from the URL, but obviously that may present problems in terms of maintenance going forward.  Or you can stick with the standard UI, which isn't the greatest UX.

To take different action based on whether you are in Salesforce1, you'll need to check for the existence of the sforce object and then direct the user to the appropriate destination based on that.  For example:

```
function navigate()
{
    if ( (typeof window.parent.sforce != 'undefined') && (window.parent.sforce!=null) ) 
    {
        sforce.one.createRecord(...);
    }
    else 
    {
        window.location='<URL including parameters>';
    }
}
```

There's more information on Salesforce1 navigation at:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm